# Problema al enviar un mensaje

Tags: c#, uwp

He hecho un fragmento de código que envía un mensaje a través de TCP/IP con sockets de un ordenador a otro. Funciona bien (envía el mensaje) si los dos ordenadores están conectados a la misma red, en cambio, si yo conecto uno de los dos ordenadores a un wifi diferente no funciona.

No se si el problema es que debo abrir puertos o si tengo que poner una IP diferente a la local del ordenador.

El fragmento de código es el siguiente:

```
private void Envio()
{
   //Ejemplo de IP
   IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.40");

   TcpClient TCP = new TcpClient();
   await TCP.ConnectAsync(IP, 443);

   Stream Str = TCP.GetStream();

   if (Str.CanWrite == true)
   {
      var Mensaje = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hola");

      if (Str != null)
      {
         Str.Write(Mensaje, 0, Mensaje.Length);
      }
   }

   TCP.Dispose();
}

private void Recepcion()
{
   IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.40");

   TcpListener TCP = new TcpListener(IP, 443);
   TCP.Start();

   MensajeB[] buffer = new byte[256];
   string Mensaje = null;

   bool Seguimiento = true;
   while (Seguimiento == true)
   {
      TcpClient TCPCl = await TCP.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
      ResultPrueba.Text = "Conectado";

      datos = null;

      NetworkStream NetStr = TCPCl.GetStream();

      int i;
      while ((i = NetStr.Read(MensajeB, 0, MensajeB.Length)) != 0)
      {
         datos = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(MensajeB, 0, i);
         ResultPrueba.Text = datos;
      }

      TCPCl.Dispose();
      if (datos.Length > 0)
      {
         Seguimiento = false;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el error que te resulta para así poder ayudarte de mejor forma,

Comment: No, no sale ningún error. Simplemente no hace nada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si conectas 2 ordenadores a distintas redes sucede lo siguiente:

-La red `A` recibe la IP pública, `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`. Y el pc `1` se le asigna una IP local: `192.168.1.40`.

-La red `B` recibe la IP pública, `yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy`. Y el pc `2` se le asigna una IP local: `192.168.1.41`.

Si estan en la misma red puedes conectar un PC al otro usando las IP's locales, pero al estar en disntintas redes no puedes comunicarte con la IP local sin pasar por la IP pública. Para eso tienes que conectarte a la IP publica, es decir al router, por ejemplo de `A`. Y para que eso funcione tienes que abrir el puerto que quieras usar, y redirigir el tráfico de ese puerto a la IP local correspondiente, en este caso `1`.

Probablemente puedes conseguir una guia de como hacer esto de tu ISP, o sino simplemente buscarlo.

Comment: Pero claro, en el caso de que esta aplicación sea para un chat que utilice gente que no sabe como abrir puertos y redirigir el tráfico, ¿no hay otra manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Si esta aplicacion es usuario-usuario, entonces es un problema. Esto se soluciona siendo una aplicación usuario-servidor-usuario, es decir, los mensajes pasan por el servidor y son enviados al destinatario. De esta forma solo es necesario abrir los puertos del servidor.

Comment: Pero cuando el servidor envíe la respuesta, el usuario no deberá abrir puertos?